# Notation for a vector with superscript and subscript

Tags: linear-algebra

In this equation where x is a vector (Euclidean norm):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/alSnj.png

How do I read this part:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEcQt.png

I think its Einstein notation but I haven't been able to find anything about a vector with a superscript and subscript at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's just the square of $x_i$. The sum of such squares over $i$ is $x_ix_i$ or $x_ix^i$ in Einstein notation.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that! Thank you.